# What type of capacitor (varistor?) is this?

Tags: identification

I inherited a prototype to document, but came across this single capacitor (varistor?) on the 24VDC input (a polarized cap symbol designated as "PS1"; see schematic image) with no value. The schematic was made in DipTrace, but the symbol used seems to have been a generic one, with no additional info (generated BoM isn't helpful, here).

The capacitor has no markings so there are no model numbers, and both sides look identical (doesn't seem to actually be a polarized cap).

What type of capacitor is this, and is there any good reason it would be designated as "PS"? Any additional insight, e.g. a typical value used here, is appreciated, too.[image]

[image]

Comment: It can't possibly be a capacitor as it's obviously meant to conduct DC.

Comment: @user_1818839 Doh! Complete oversight on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it is in series with the rest of the circuit and its size/shape would seem to indicate a polyfuse or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that's a [polyfuse](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/656941.pdf) or similar Positive Temperature Coefficient resistor, acting as a current limiter.